# Pass variable from js function to gsap scrollTrigger

Tags: javascript, function, variables, gsap, scrolltrigger

trying to modify gsap scrollTrigger **offset_value** based on window width. Unfortunaly can't figure out how to achieve this with `(window).resize(function()` when user changes window size "on the fly". This function has no effect on **offset_value** variable.

This is the code now and apparently something is fundamentaly wrong in my approach:

```
    gsap.registerPlugin(ScrollTrigger);
    var frame_count  = 37,
    offset_value = 360;
if (window.innerWidth < 980) {
    offset_value = 180;
     }
//This is the part that is not working
jQuery(window).resize(function() {
  if( jQuery(this).width() > 979 ){
    offset_value=360;}
    else {offset_value=180;}
    return offset_value;
});
//END This is the part that is not working

gsap.to(".iis-viewer", {
  backgroundPosition: (-offset_value * frame_count * 2) + "px 50%",
  ease: "steps(" + frame_count + ")", // use a stepped ease for the sprite sheet
  scrollTrigger: {
    trigger: ".iis-scene",
    start: "top top",
    end: "+=" + (frame_count * offset_value),
    pin: true,
    scrub: true
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

These sort of situations are exactly what ScrollTrigger's [.matchMedia](https://greensock.com/docs/v3/Plugins/ScrollTrigger/static.matchMedia) method are for.

You can set up what you're trying to do above like so:

```
ScrollTrigger.matchMedia({
  // desktop
  "(min-width: 980px)": function() {
    const offset_value = 360;
    gsap.to(".iis-viewer", {
      backgroundPosition: (-offset_value * frame_count * 2) + "px 50%",
      ease: "steps(" + frame_count + ")", // use a stepped ease for the sprite sheet
      scrollTrigger: {
        trigger: ".iis-scene",
        start: "top top",
        end: "+=" + (frame_count * offset_value),
        pin: true,
        scrub: true
      }
    });
  },
  
  // mobile
  "(max-width: 979px)": function() {
    const offset_value = 180;
    gsap.to(".iis-viewer", {
      backgroundPosition: (-offset_value * frame_count * 2) + "px 50%",
      ease: "steps(" + frame_count + ")", // use a stepped ease for the sprite sheet
      scrollTrigger: {
        trigger: ".iis-scene",
        start: "top top",
        end: "+=" + (frame_count * offset_value),
        pin: true,
        scrub: true
      }
    });
  }
});
```

However, since your use case is just switching out a couple of values (instead of requiring different tweens/ScrollTriggers) it probably makes more sense to just use functional values because functional values are updated when ScrollTrigger refreshes (on resize):

```
let offset_value;

function updateOffsetValue() {
  offset_value = innerWidth > 979 ? 360 : 180;
}

window.addEventListener("resize", updateOffsetValue);
updateOffsetValue();

gsap.to(".iis-viewer", {
  backgroundPosition: () => (-offset_value * frame_count * 2) + "px 50%",
  ease: "steps(" + frame_count + ")", // use a stepped ease for the sprite sheet
  scrollTrigger: {
    trigger: ".iis-scene",
    start: "top top",
    end: () => "+=" + (frame_count * offset_value),
    pin: true,
    scrub: true
  }
});
```

Comment: Note that you're more likely to get an ever faster response over on [the GreenSock forums](https://greensock.com/forums/). Happy tweening!

Comment: Thanks for your help! The first solution made it :-) 
Couldn't get the second one to work (Value did not change on window resize), maybe because animation is inside wordpress and divi theme? 
And also thanks for the tip about GS forum. Cheers!

Comment: Hard to say what the issue is without seeing the error or full code. If an answer got you a solution you should click the check mark next to it to mark it as accepted.